# php Array how to iterate

Tags: php, arrays

I am using a code-igniter query which returns the the array below with additional calculated `[year_totalsales]` added to array.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [year] => 2009 [month] => November [month_sales] => 524 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) [1] => Array ( [year] => 2009 [month] => December [month_sales] => 521 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) [2] => Array ( [year] => 2010 [month] => January [month_sales] => 609 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) [3] => Array ( [year] => 2010 [month] => February [month_sales] => 619 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) [4] => Array ( [year] => 2010 [month] => March [month_sales] => 732 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) [5] => Array ( [year] => 2010 [month] => April [month_sales] => 605 [year_totalsales] => 3610 ) )
```

Is there a way to get the output result to look this:

```
year-------------------------

month---------------monthsales
```

Answer (score 1):

well you could do something like:

```
<?
$myarray = array( 0 => array( 'year' => 2009, 'month' => "November", 'month_sales' => 524, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ),
1 => array ( 'year' => 2009, 'month' => 'December', 'month_sales' => 521, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ),
                  2 => array ( 'year' => 2010, 'month' => "January", 'month_sales' => 609, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ));

$linewidth = 29; // Change to the width you want of course
$sep = "-"; // Change the seperator you want
$lastyear = "";
function pad($output, $length) {
    global $sep;
    $output = (string)$output;
    while (strlen($output) < $length) {
        $output .= $sep;
    }
    return $output;
}
foreach($myarray as $row) {
    if ($row['year'] != $lastyear) {
        echo pad($row['year'], $linewidth), PHP_EOL;
        $lastyear = $row['year'];
    }
    echo pad($row['month'], $linewidth-strlen((string)$row['month_sales'])), $row['month_sales'], PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Of course you could add your own formatting or whatever if this isn't satisfactory.

Edit: tested, it works properly now.

Outputs:

```
2009-------------------------
November------------------524
December------------------521
2010-------------------------
January-------------------609
```

Edit this uses an HTML table instead:

```
<?
$myarray = array( 0 => array( 'year' => 2009, 'month' => "November", 'month_sales' => 524, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ),
1 => array ( 'year' => 2009, 'month' => 'December', 'month_sales' => 521, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ),
                  2 => array ( 'year' => 2010, 'month' => "January", 'month_sales' => 609, 'year_totalsales' => 3610 ));

$lastyear = "";
echo "<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Sales</th></tr>", PHP_EOL;
foreach($myarray as $row) {
    if ($row['year'] != $lastyear) {
        echo "<tr><th colspan=2>", $row['year'], "</th></tr>", PHP_EOL;
        $lastyear = $row['year'];
    }
    echo "<tr><td>", $row['month'], "</td><td>", $row['month_sales'], "</td></tr>", PHP_EOL;
}
echo "</table>", PHP_EOL;
?>
```

This outputs:

```
<table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Sales</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan=2>2009</th></tr>
<tr><td>November</td><td>524</td></tr>
<tr><td>December</td><td>521</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan=2>2010</th></tr>
<tr><td>January</td><td>609</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your idea seems to be what I am lookingto achieve. But throwing it into a design seem to not do what it is supposed to which is:
<h3>Year - Total</h3>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

Comment: Your idea seems to be what I am lookingto achieve. But throwing it into a design seem to not do what it is supposed to which is:
<h3>Year(2009) - Total</h3>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>month</td>
<td>sales</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>month</td>
<td>sales</td>
</tr>
etc............
</table>
</div>
<h3>year(2010) - Total</h3>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>month</td>
<td>sales</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>month</td>
<td>sales</td>
</tr>
etc............
</table>
</div>

Comment: CODE IS BELOW:
<?php
if( !empty($data)){
$lastyear = "";
foreach($data as $row) {
if ($row['year'] != $lastyear) {
<h3><a href="#"><?=$row['year']?> - Total <?=$row['year_totalsales']?></a></h3>
<?php
$lastyear = $row['year'];
}
?>
<div>
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th width="10%">Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?=$row['month']?></td>
<td><?=$row['month_sales']?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>

Comment: I added a table implementation. You can see it in the answer as an edit.

Comment: Wow thx for the reply. I am still a noob PHP dude but I do learn from other...:-)

THing is I actually needed a table for each year... :-)

Comment: Any ideas yet as I seem unable to achieve splitting the data into seperate table years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($year_array as $months_array)
{
echo 'year        '.$year_array[0];
foreach($months_array as $months)
{
echo 'monthsales        '.$months[0];
}
}
```

Comment: It's generally better to avoid embedding loops inside of loops because it kills your algorithm's efficiency. Here's a good resource to learn more if you wish -- http://bit.ly/bOow9P

Comment: @Stephen - While I agree that's a great site, you just linked to about 36 hours of video with no hint at where to find the information regarding embedded loops. Care to narrow it down a little?

Comment: It's a whole class on Algorithms, including asymptotic analysis. What you're probably wanting to know about is "Big O" notation and asymptotic analysis - it outlines what patterns are most efficient and such

Comment: Start on the first video at about 17:20

Comment: (off-topic) @Syntax Error - I checked out your website and I think you should see this article http://bit.ly/d23hQC

Comment: Hi there,
Your solutions prints out:
year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Jmonthsales 6monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Fmonthsales 6monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Mmonthsales 7monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Amonthsales 6monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Mmonthsales 7monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Jmonthsales 8monthsales year Arraymonthsales 2monthsales Jmonthsales 9monthsales

Answer (score 0):

`printf` could be used quite well to accomplish this. [PHP.net docs for sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf) has the details on what the formatting options are.

```
foreach ($month_data as $m) {
    printf("%d\n%20s $%.2lf\n", $m['year'], $m['month'], $m['month_sales']);
}
```

If you wanted to only print unique years, as suggested in the comments, you could try this.

```
$current_year = null;
foreach ($month_data as $m) {
    if ($current_year != $m['year']) {
        printf("%d\n", $m['year']);
        $current_year = $m['year'];
    }
    printf("%20s $%.2lf\n", $m['month'], $m['month_sales']);
}
```

Comment: I think he is looking for a way to only display the year once instead of before each month.